# null context in constructor of adapter class in android

Tags: android, constructor, null, adapter, android-context

Hey guys i have this adapter class and i want it to pass photos to gridview and i passed context and urls of photos to the constructor but it seems that they are null < can any one tell me what is the problem ?

```
public class MovieAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final String LOG_TAG = MovieAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    public  final String urlBase = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185";
    private final Context context;
    private  String[] urls;

    public MovieAdapter(Context context, String[] urls) {
        this.context = context;
        this.urls = urls;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return urls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return urls[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = new ImageView(context);
        }
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        String url = (String) getItem(position);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG , "URL " + url);
        Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does the error occur? how are you creating the `urls` `String` `array`?

Comment: please post the code where you create the MovieAdapter object

Comment: Don't sure but maybe you need set parent view for child's views. Really, post code how you use this class.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourAdapterObj= new MovieAdapter ("Your Activity Name", "Your url arraylist");
yourgridview.setAdapter(yourAdapterObj);
```

pass proper activityClass name ActivityClass.this